# A specific confusion on writing an async function. Can anyone validate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I am very new to NodeJS. I was trying to get a function written that can simply return a configuration value from DB. I might need to call it multiple times.

In PHP or other synchronous languages, I would use the following code for it

```
function getConfigValue($configKeyName)
{

// DB READ OPERATIONS

return $confguration_value_fetched_from_db

}

getConfigValue("key1");
getConfigValue("key2");
```

etc

But in NodeJS, I found it too difficult to do this operation because of the Asynchronous nature of the code. After asking some questions here, and after spending hours to learn Callbacks, Promises, Async/await keywords, being a beginner the below is best code I could reach.

```
    // Below function defines the 'get' function

            var get = async (key) => {

              var result = await COLLECTIONNAME.findOne({key}); //MongoDB in backend

              return result.value;

            }

        // Here I am forced to define another async function so that I can await for the get function.

            function async anotherfunction()
            {

            var value_I_am_lookingfor1 = await get("key1");

            var value_I_am_lookingfor2 = await get("key2");

            }

            anotherfunction();
```

While it might work, I am not fully happy with the result, mainly because I really don't want to do all my further coding based on the fetched value within this function anotherfunction(). All I want is to fetch a single value? Also I might need to easily call it from many places within the application, not just from here (I was planning to place it in a module)

Any better or easier methods? Or should I always get the value I want, and then nest it with a 'then.' to do the subsequent operation? I even doubt the fundamental approach I take on NodeJS coding itself may be wrong.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Does `findOne` return a `Promise` or does it use a callback? It probably doesn't do both - either handle it as a `Promise`, or pass a callback, but don't mix the two.

Comment: In the documentation of findOne (mongoose findone), I see that it returns callback. But to use await, I need a promise. So I used that too, but it worked!

Comment: ok, Now I removed the callback, it works good, just with the promise. So I am editing the question too. Thanks!

Comment: After editing, the code looks a bit more simpler, BUT, my fundamental problem of being forced to write all subsequent code within the anotherfunction() i still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mainly because I really don't want to do all my further coding based on the fetched value within this function anotherfunction(). All I want is to fetch a single value?

Because the request is asynchronous, and your code depends on having the fetched values first, there's no option *other* than to wait for the values to be retrieved before continuing. *Somewhere* in the script, control flow needs to halt until the values are retrieved before other parts of the script continue.

> Also I might need to easily call it from many places within the application, not just from here (I was planning to place it in a module)

You should have that module make the requests and export a Promise that resolves to the values needed. Rather than using `await` (which forces requests to be processed *in serial*), you should probably use `Promise.all`, which will allow multiple requests to be sent out at once. For example:

valuegetter.js

```
const get = key => COLLECTIONNAME.findOne({ key }).then(res => res.value);
export default Promise.all([
  get('key1'),
  get('key2')
]);
```

main.js

```
import prom from './valuegetter.js';
prom.then(([val1, val2]) => {
  // do stuff with val1 and val2
})
.catch((err) => {
  // handle errors
});
```

If other modules need `val1` and `val2`, call them from `main.js` with the values they need.